# Division by zero using // operator in python

Tags: python, calculator

Running the following code:

```
p = int(input("principal: "))
interest = int(input("annual interest rate: "))
years = int(input("# of years: "))

r = interest // 100

n = years * 12

top = r * (1 + r) ** n

bottom = (1+r) ** n - 1

fraction = top // bottom

A = fraction * p
print(A)
```

I get:

```
line 17, in <module>
    fraction = top // bottom
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

I am a beginner, please be kind!

Comment: "ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero". As the error says, `bottom` is 0. Check the rest of your data to see why.

Answer (score 0):

The floor division `//` rounds the result down to the nearest whole number (data type = **integer**) and `r` as an integer will be 0 when `interest` is *<100*.

You can see what happens with `top` if `r` equals `0`.

Same thing with `fraction` and the `//` operator. Use `round` to round the numbers.

```
p = int(input("principal: "))
interest = int(input("annual interest rate: "))
years = int(input("# of years: "))

r = interest / 100
n = years * 12
top = r * (1 + r) ** n
bottom = (1+r) ** n - 1
fraction = top / bottom

A = round(fraction * p, 2)
print(A)
```